Is creating merry christmas poster for my school haram?
I am working in a school and as a computer teacher I have to create posters for different festivals celebrated in our country India....So is it allowed for me to do this ...am I doing shirk?....but I don't believe in their concepts and only believe in one and only Allah ....please guide me what to do.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/50074
